# What's wrong with this http request? Is there a validator somewhere?

Tags: validation, http, request

I'm trying to send an http request but get 400 Bad Request from the server. How do I know what's wrong? Is there an http request validator somewhere on the web? If not, can somebody explain why this request fails:

```
GET http://www.example.com/index.htm HTTP/1.1
connection: close
content-length: 0
```

The request does end in \r\n\r\n.

Comment: Welcome! Check the standard and equip yourself with an overview of which parameters are eligible for requests vs. replies, in general, and for which HTTP methods, in specific.

Comment: Consult [RFC7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) to create standards-compliant HTTP requests.

Comment: Not everyone knows which docs to read. Some still read the obsolete RFC2616. Some read non-official versions like Wikipedia, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51575349/9490942) for example. Also, the wording can be confusing and the unfamiliar terms may require reading the entire document. In such cases, asking on SO allows one to reach a decision with confidence by getting answers from someone experienced (see the answer to that question). In your case, the spec says "A client MUST send a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages." which is short and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: With http 1.1 the host header is required. When I added that header the request succeded and I received the expected response.